# Unable to connect to service in a docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net5

I have a created a .net 5 based service. This service works well locally. I am trying to put this into a docker container. However I am unable to connect to it. Service is running using Kestrel configured for 8080

My Dockerfile is fairly straight forward

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 #msft image

COPY ./bin/debug/net5.0/ .        #local items

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [dotnet, myservice.dll]
```

Command used to run the service

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 myservice
```

I have created an image and when I run the above image with `-it` flag I can see the service is executed. On inspecting/exporting of the container I can also see some application log files generated, indicating service is running successfully. When I run the swagger endpoint by executing curl inside container I do get the swagger UI HTML page.

However when I run this from my actual machine it doesn't seem to connect to any of the endpoints. I have run the image using `-p 8080:8080` so it should respond on same port. I have tried using random local port maps, so certainly ports are not blocked.

I have also checked running another container based services on port 8080 but I am able to access the same, so definitely port is not blocked.

Not sure what am I missing here. Setup is pretty simple since its just a dummy service for testing with one swagger endpoint and another weatherforecast endpoint that comes with .net template.

Comment: Make sure you did not type `exit` in bash window after executing `run`. Or better yet, try running your image without `-it` flag and then try to access it. It is possible that after entering into bash window, you may be exiting from there which terminates container. Also while trying to access from your machine, first run `docker ps` and check that your container is running.

Comment: @LUC1F3R, Thank you for the response however very certain I have not exited and container is running. Have also tried running it using docker UI just to be sure however same behavior.

Comment: @semicolon : Thanks for suggestions. I got this resolved. Service configuration was hardcoded to listen to localhost, which was what was causing the issue. Switched it to 0.0.0.0 for now and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

By default the container will be listening internally on port 80 unless you have overridden that using the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable. `EXPOSE` in the Docker file doesn't do anything but document the ports intended to be used.

Try to run it with `-p 8080:80` which will map port 8080 on the local machine to port 80 in the container.